# Why socket does not connect with ip instead of localhost?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server, ip-address

I am trying to connect to server via ip address but it does not work. Both are in the same machine and when I change ipAddress to localhost it works. What would be the reason for that?

```
try {
    String ipAddress = "46.155.17.100";
    int port = 8082;

    // Create a socket to connect to the server
    socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);

    toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

} catch (Exception ex) {
    connected = false;
    try {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

EDİT : When I change my connection from WiFi to internet cable, socket is connected with new ip address. But I dont know why :(

Comment: Check your firewall, try to ping this ip address

Comment: This is most likely and issue with a firewall or incorrect IP address.

Comment: Does your computer accept incoming connections? Mine doesn’t.

Comment: Please show your computers network configuration on your local machine working and then not working. So we can see your addressing.

Comment: It is a well formatted post, and also it is interesting. So, you get here an upvote. Don't forget to accept the answer which solved your problem, by clicking the pipe icon on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to connect to server via ip address but it does not work.
>   Both are in the same machine and when I change ipAddress to localhost
>   it works. What would be the reason for that?

The reason for that is because your ServerSocket in the server code is not bound to the IP-Address which you're trying to connect from the client. So, in that case, the ServerSocket is bound to the default loopback address, i.e.,the `localhost` OR `127.0.0.1`.

You need to edit your server side code to bind the IP-Address of ServerSocket with the IP(`46.155.17.100`) either in the constructor OR binding it later. It would be done by replacing the ServerSocket initialisation with the following :

```
// int port = 4444, backlog = 5;
String bindaddr = "46.155.17.100";
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port,backlog,InetAddress.getByName(bindAddr));
// your server-side code continues below.
```

Comment: It wont matter where he or how he binds the address. That address is not routable in his internal network unless he is NOT using private IPs or has static routes for that address.

Comment: @Underbalanced - You too are unsure whether he is connected to that network. I know because I've seen newbies asking this similar question repeatedly. This might turn out to be OP's public address!
Beware, remove your downvote once my words turn correct(OP accepts the answer).

Comment: I also am agreement that this might be the OPs public address. Really his details are lacking. If he is on a LAN with a different sub net. Then how is he going to bind to his routers public address?

Comment: @Underbalanced - Well, you should not presume everything as per your wish. Who knows, what I mentioned maybe the case with OP!

Answer (score -1):

Networking fundamentals (In a Gist): When using a IP address, your computer is going to look to see if the IP is on the same sub-net as its own NIC(s). If not the computer will defer to routing to your default gateway (router) in determining the location of the address. So when you use the public address you are sending the traffic from your computer to your router, and then out to the ISP/Service provider where it simply gets routed back to your routers IP and thus your router needs to be open for the traffic on port 8082. Using localhost or 127.0.0.1 tells your computer to route it to itself.

```
In Steps:
Destination "46.155.17.100"
Computer is this in my local network?(My own network is 192.168.0.0/24) (My Address is 192.168.0.X)
    - This is not on my network, let me send it to my default gateway
Computer sends data to gateway -> 192.168.0.1 (router)
The Router says, is this on any network I know of?
        - Nope i do not own 46.155.17.100, -> Your router send data to its own default gateway which should be the (ISP Router)
ISP Router says hey i know where this is -> sends it back to your router.
```

Comment: Adding this answer shows that you are unaware of SO's way of what/how to answer. OP is not asking for the basics of Networking, he is asking for fault in the code!!! SO is not a theoretical Networking Stack Exchange, it is a programming-related website. You need to answer OP's problem in the related code, which this answer hardly touches!

Answer (score -2):

first try "telnet 46.155.17.100 8802". If telnet can't connect to the server, the problem is with the server, or with the firewall.